# Uploading csv file with bigmemory package

Tags: r, csv, r-bigmemory

I have a csv file and want to open it with the "bigmemory" package.

I am using R 2.15.3.

This is the code:

```
library(bigmemory)
library(biganalytics)
x<-read.big.matrix('data.csv')
```

After I did this, R crashed. I do not know what the data looks like.

If anyone has any ideas it would be really helpful. Also I researched that R 2.15.3 is the only version that supports this, if that is not true then it would be good to know. Thanks

Comment: I just installed both using R 3.2.1. Not sure where you're getting your data about 2.15.3 but it looks like its a bit out-dated. Also, are you on Windows? The [official website](http://www.bigmemory.org) mentions upcoming compatibility with Windows but it may not be available yet.

Comment: @scribbles Is the code to read the csv correct or do I need to add anything else to it?

Comment: @scribbles I am on Windows.

Comment: @Nick you can download the most recent version from our github repo (I am one of the developers).  Just use `devtools::install_github("kaneplusplus/bigmemory")` with your most recent R version.  The current windows build is functional.  Check that and report back.

Comment: @Nick nothing is inherently wrong with your `read` code though you may need to specify `sep =`, `header =`, etc. based on your actual file format.

Comment: Does it matter what the size of the file is using this package? Because the size is 50 GB. @scribbles

Comment: Windows
Error : Invalid DESCRIPTION file

Malformed Depends or Suggests or Imports or Enhances field.
Offending entries:
  Suggests: knitr
Entries must be names of packages optionally followed by '<=' or '>=',
white space, and a valid version number in parentheses.

See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
manual.

@cdeterman ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'bigmemory'
* removing 'C:/Users/Nicholas/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/bigmemory'
Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: Based on past experiences I don't anticipate it being an issue but @cdeterman would probably be the best person to ask.

Comment: @cdeterman yeah for some reason I can't download your github repo. I've tested on other github repo's and it works. Not sure what is wrong

Comment: @Nick, odd, it compiles locally but fails on the `install_github`.  I will need to look in to this.  Try just cloning the whole repo and create a new project in Rstudio and then build it in their.  That still works for me on Windows.  Not sure why the git repo is acting up.

Comment: @cdeterman do I just click on the "Clone in Desktop" button?

Comment: @cdeterman The problem is in the description file

Comment: @Nick, you can clone it to your desktop or download it as a `.zip`. The `.zip` option is probably easiest. Once downloaded use `devtool::install("path_to_your_downloaded_.zip_file")`

Comment: @cdeterman Error in parse_git_repo(repo) : Invalid git repo: /bigmemory-master (1)

Comment: @Nick, wow, somehow I overlooked that we had two `Suggests` statements.  Now try installing from my personal fork `install_github('cdeterman/bigmemory')`

Comment: @cdeterman Thanks I am currently trying to download the data, not sure how long it will take since it's 50 GB. Will I be able to use the biganalytics library with this as well?

Comment: @cdeterman R crashed. I think the file must be too big

Comment: You should be able to load it.  Try `read.big.matrix('data.csv', backingfile="example.bin", descriptorfile="example.desc")`.  That should create a `filebacked.big.matrix` where the size can be bigger than available RAM.  That is the idea behind the package.

Comment: @cdeterman can I just call the backfile and descriptorfile example.bin and example.desc or do I need to specify this on my desktop before running it? Basically will it automatically make the backingfile and descriptorfile by typing this in the code?

Comment: It automatically creates the backing files.  You can name them whatever you want *.bin and *.desc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87398/discussion-between-nick-and-cdeterman).